# Positioning new SKSpriteNodes at corners of existing rotated SKSpriteNode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geometry, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I need to spawn 4 new `SKSpriteNodes` (independent not parented) at the corners of an existing sprite. Its pretty basic stuff but I am struggling to find the correct formula, I though I had it but its not working as expected. Could some either point me towards the correct formula or help me out with some guidance on calculating the 4 [x, y] pairs for any given rotation. Much appreciated.

[image]

1. Move rotation center for each point to origin.
2. xnew = x * cos(angle) - y * sin(angle)
3. ynew = y * cos(angle) + x * sin(angle)
4. Move rotation center for each point back to original position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CGPointApplyAffineTransform` along with `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` if you didn't want to do the math yourself. Your math though looks almost right at first glance, I believe you just need to subtract out the center point. So xnew would be (x - x_c) * cos(a) - (y - y_c) * sin(a). Can't test right now so can't be 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I will look at those, much appreciated.

Comment: Matt, I have not had chance to try this yet but I have read the docs and it would seem to be just what I need, thank you again for taking the time to answer.